# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_35.lib'

Tags: c#, c++, sdk

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_35.lib'
```

I am getting this error while trying to build a project using visual studio 2008. Previously i was using VS2005 with SDK v6.0, now i upgraded it to 2008(and SDK v.7.0 ) and trying to run the same project.
(above mentioned library file is not there in my project).

Answer (score 1):

c++ compiler in VS2008 is vc9.0, so the compiler require the corresponding boost libarary--'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_35.lib'. You can find the path of 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_35.lib' and add it to the project or compile it from the boost source code.